# service content when duplicated does not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have owl carousel when duplicate the content it wont display why is that

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc94b1fh/)

```
       <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div id="service-slider" class="owl-carousel">
      <!--Service item 1 -->
 <div class="item">
<div class="service-items">
    <img class="img-circle service-slider-image" 
        src="images/service-slider1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="service-details">
        <h3>Engagement  Make up</h3>
        <!--                                        
            <p>Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without 
            functional solutions. Completely synergize resource </p>
                                            --><!--                                         
            <a href="#" class="more-service"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                             -->                                 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which content ? the `<p>` under the `<h3>` ?

Comment: With your fiddle I can't reproduce your issue. Please add an working example.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i don't understand correctly your issue. but why don't you remove `hide content signs`

see below

```html
<section id="service">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="theme-title-area">
                                <h2>SERVICES</h2>
                                <h6>— What can I do for you?</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- service slider -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div id="service-slider" class="owl-carousel">
                            <!--Service item 1 -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="service-items">
                                    <img class="img-circle service-slider-image" src="images/service-slider1.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="service-details">
                                        <h3>Engagement  Make up</h3>
                                                                             <p>Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions. Completely synergize resource </p>
                                                                                  <a href="#" class="more-service"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                                      
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--END OF Service item 1 -->
                            <!--Service item 2 -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="service-items">
                                    <img class="img-circle service-slider-image" src="images/service-slider2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="service-details">
                                        <h3>Pre-Wedding  Make up</h3>
                                        <!--                                        <p>Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions. Completely synergize resource </p>
                                            --><!--                                         <a href="#" class="more-service"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                            -->                                 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--END OF Service item 2 -->
                            <!--Service item 3 -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="service-items">
                                    <img class="img-circle service-slider-image" src="images/service-slider3.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="service-details">
                                        <h3>Reception Make up</h3>
                                                                        <p>Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions. Completely synergize resource </p>
                                                                                  <a href="#" class="more-service"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                                     
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--END OF Service item 3 -->
                            <!--Service item 4 -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="service-items">
                                    <img class="img-circle service-slider-image" src="images/service-slider1.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="service-details">
                                        <h3>Celebrity Make </h3>
                                                                           <p>Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions. Completely synergize resource </p>
                                                                             <a href="#" class="more-service"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--END OF Service item 4 -->
                            <!--Service item 5 -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="service-items">
                                    <img class="img-circle service-slider-image" src="images/service-slider2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="service-details">
                                        <h3>Fashion</h3>
                                                                       <p>Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions. Completely synergize resource </p>
                                                                            <a href="#" class="more-service"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                               
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--END OF Service item 5 -->
                            <!--Service item 6 -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="service-items">
                                    <img class="img-circle service-slider-image" src="images/service-slider3.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="service-details">
                                        <h3>Hair Styles</h3>
                                                                       <p>Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions. Completely synergize resource </p>
                                                                                <a href="#" class="more-service"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                                     
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--END OF Service item 6 -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of service slider -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of service slider -->
        </section>
```